# Compiling Bitcoin Core 0.21.1 on Apple M1 architecture

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling, mac

I'd like to upgrade from 0.21.0 to 0.21.1 on Mac Mini (Big Sur 11.1), compiling from source. When trying to compile the dependencies by running 'make' in /depends subdirectory, I get the following error:

`ERROR: Feature 'system-zlib' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.zlib' failed. make: *** [/Users/xxx/bitcoin/depends/work/build/arm-apple-darwin20.2.0/qt/5.9.8-82a1b93ac0c/qtbase/.stamp_configured] Error 3`

Any advice on how to solve this would be appreciated!

Comment: Core doesn't yet support building on M1, see this PR https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20371. Not many testers with M1 hardware it appears so please do comment on the PR and help with testing :)

Comment: Thanks for the link; I'll hop over to github, will be happy to contribute testing! Oddly enough, I was able to build 0.21.0 (or a few commits afterwards), though boost and qt were some issues initially.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on tag v0.21.1 on my M1 macbook pro (Big Sur 11.4).

It turned out that i COULD "make /depends" on master. Then, however, even on master currently, "./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/depends/aarch64-apple-darwin20.5.0" won't finish successfuly (it can't find a specific QT lib).

To get v0.21.1 to compile on Apple silicon, I followed the build manual doc/build-osx.md.
In particular, homebrew seems to provide all relevant dependencies apple silicon compiled as of now.

BUT, "./configure" as follows:

- apply jonasschnelli's getauxval fix mentioned in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20371 **
- export CPPFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags libevent)
- ./configure --with-boost=$(brew --prefix boost)

A "make -j 8" should then make Bob your uncle.

** cherry-picking the proper solution from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20603 didn't work for me due to merge conflicts

Regards,

Gebert